# How to use "select" method to reduce data transfer when using Eager Loading

Tags: laravel, select

I have a API and its taking long time to get all the info and its because I'm only hidding some data but I want to omit not to hidde. I found `select()` method to chose wich data send and reduce the time to query all information I really need. 
Im trying to use `select` just after the relation just like this, just to retrieve only name from `OPR_User` table:

```
public function creatorUser() {
  return $this->belongsTo('Knotion\OPR_User', 'idCreatorUser', 'idUser')->select('name');
}
```

but is not working
This is my Model code

```
<?php

namespace Knotion;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CTL_Resource extends Model  {

    protected $table = "CTL_Resource";
    protected $primaryKey = "idResource";

    public $incrementing = false;
    public $timestamps = false;
    public static $snakeAttributes = false;

    protected $hidden = [
      'coachVisibility', 'thumbnail',
      'studentVisibility', 'isHTML','studentIndex', 'coachIndex',
      'isURL', 'source', 'path', 'status', 'updateTime', 'isfolder',
      'parentResource', 'idModifierUser', 'idResourceType', 'idCreatorUser', 'idCreationCountry'
    ];

    protected $fillable = ['idResourceType','productionKey', 'idCreatorUser', 'idModifierUser', 'idCreationCountry', 'title', 'description', 'URL', 'fileName', 'extension', 'minimumAge', 'maximumAge', 'productionKey'];

    public function creatorUser() {
      return $this->belongsTo('Knotion\OPR_User', 'idCreatorUser', 'idUser');
    }
    public function creationCountry() {
      return $this->belongsTo('Knotion\CTL_Country', 'idCreationCountry', 'idCountry');
    }
    public function resourceType()  {
      return $this->belongsTo('Knotion\CTL_ResourceType', 'idResourceType', 'idResourceType');
    }
    public function quickTags() {
      return $this->belongsToMany('Knotion\CTL_QuickTag', 'CTL_Resource_has_QuickTags', 'idResource','idQuickTag');
    }
    public function tags() {
      return $this->belongsToMany('Knotion\CTL_Tag','CTL_Resource_has_Tags', 'idResource', 'idTag');
    }
    public function relatedTo() {
      return $this->belongsToMany('Knotion\CTL_RelatedTo', 'CTL_Resource_has_RelatedTo', 'idResource', 'idRelatedTo');
    }

}
```

this is my relation model code (just in case needed):

```
<?php

namespace Knotion;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class OPR_User extends Model  {
  protected $table = "OPR_User";
  protected $primaryKey = "idUser";

  public $incrementing = false;
  public $timestamps = false;
  public static $snakeAttributes = false;

  protected $hidden = ['firstName', 'secondName', 'firstSurName', 'secondSurName', 'password', 'picture', 'status', 'createTime', 'updateTime', 'idUserType', 'email'];

  public function resources() {
    return $this->hasMany('Knotion\CTL_Resource', 'idResource');
  }
  public function userType() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Knotion\CTL_UserType', 'idUserType', 'idUserType');
  }

}
```

and this is my Controller code:

```
    public function index(Request $request)    {

    $resources = CTL_Resource::all();

    $resources->resourceType->select('name');

      return $resources->load('creatorUser', 'creationCountry', 'resourceType', 'tags', 'quickTags', 'relatedTo');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add the ->select after the ->belongsTo it's no longer an actual relationship type, it's a query builder. You need to add the select afterwards before you call the ->load.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment. I had to include the id to work, I did post the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem I had to include the id also in the relation, something like this:

```
 public function resources() {
    return $this->hasMany('Knotion\CTL_Resource', 'idResource')->select('idResource', 'name');
  }
```